# How to add a new menu in WooCommerce as My Orders (backend)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to make a copy of Orders menu as My Orders. That will be listed inside WooCommerce main menu.

[image]

I have made a WooCommerce folder in my plugin to override template files. Is there any way to use hooks, filters or action to achieve the results?

*WooCommerce version* `2.4.12`

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Add Menu to WC
 */

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'admin_menu' );
function admin_menu() {
$page = add_submenu_page( 'woocommerce', __( 'My Orders', 'my_text_domain' ), __( 'My Orders', 'my_text_domain' ), apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_roles', 'manage_woocommerce' ), 'my_orders_page', 'output');
}
```

Try this code snippet

Comment: Re : I want to make a copy of Orders menu as My Orders